# I can't install python-ldap

Tags: python, module, ldap, python-ldap

When I run the following command:

```
sudo pip install python-ldap
```

I get this error:

> In file included from Modules/LDAPObject.c:9:
>
> Modules/errors.h:8: fatal error: lber.h: No such file or directory

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 629, accepted):

The [python-ldap](http://www.python-ldap.org/) is based on OpenLDAP, so you need to have the development files (headers) in order to compile the Python module. If you're on Ubuntu, the package is called `libldap2-dev`.

**[Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)/[Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)**:

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev python-dev-is-python3 libldap2-dev libssl-dev
```

**[Red Hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux)/[CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS)**:

```
sudo yum install python-devel openldap-devel
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It's got further it's now failing with sasl.h no such file or directory

Comment: @VacuumTube: Missing headers are almost always a sign for missing `-dev` packages (sometimes also named `-devel`). Just do `apt-cache search sasl | grep dev` and you'll probably find the right package - I would guess it's `libsasl2-dev`.

Comment: Anything for windows users :( Same error, no solutions so far

Comment: You don't have to compile from source on Windows. Just use one of the installers from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ldap/.

Comment: Also, Windows users can extract the .msi installer @Semmel mentioned to install into a virtualenv: [How to install python-ldap on a python 2.7 virtualenv on windows without compiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918188/how-to-install-python-ldap-on-a-python-2-7-virtualenv-on-windows-without-compili) (see update 2)

Comment: On Windows you can also use Chris Gohlke's excellent resource for Windows installers: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap

Comment: Thanks @AndiDog. the issue was resolved as soon as I installed the `-dev` library :)

Comment: Full list should be sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev python-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev

Comment: Notice that you need to run 'sudo apt-get update' first.

Comment: Well this is odd. I have installed `libldap2-dev` but the headers haven't been installed. Everything else in the package (libs, man pages) has. Edit: --reinstall and it's fine.

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu: Why this that the full list? Can you explain how you found those dependencies?

Comment: @Lii I found out that one since 2015. It may not correct now

Comment: Use `python3-dev` instead of `python-dev` if you are using Python 3.

Comment: Sometimes also known as `python36-devel` or `python3-devel.x86_64` or `python36-devel.x86_64` (aws). When in doubt: `yum search python | grep -i dev`

Comment: Worth noting in 2022 on Debian 11, I only needed to install `libldap2-dev` and `libsasl2-dev`. (Already had `python3-virtualenv`.)

Comment: for me it didn't find `python-dev` so I did this: `sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev python-dev-is-python3 libldap2-dev libssl-dev`

Comment: I have to remove `python-dev` parameter to fix the problem

Answer (score 158):

To install python-ldap successfully with pip, following development libraries are needed (package names taken from ubuntu environment):

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 74):

On [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS)/[RHEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) 6, you need to install:

```
sudo yum install python-devel
sudo yum install openldap-devel
```

And [YUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yum_(software)) will also install  `cyrus-sasl-devel` as a dependency.  Then you can run:

```
pip-2.7 install python-ldap
```

Answer (score 54):

#### "Don't blindly remove/install software"

In a Ubuntu or Debian-based distribution, you can use [`apt-file`](https://wiki.debian.org/apt-file) to find the name of the exact package that includes the missing header file.

```bash
# Do this once
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

---

```bash
apt-file search lber.h
```

Output:

```
libldap2-dev: /usr/include/lber.h
```

As you could see from the output of `apt-file search lber.h`, you'd just need to install the package `libldap2-dev`.

```
sudo apt-get install libldap2-dev
```

Comment: Is there a CentoOS equivalent to this?

Answer (score 35):

In Ubuntu it looks like this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libssl-dev
sudo pip install python-ldap
```

Answer (score 17):

Windows: I completely agree with the accepted answer, but digging through the comments took a while to get to the meat of what I needed.  I ran across this specific problem with Reviewboard on Windows using the [Bitnami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitnami#Technology_overview).  To give an answer for Windows then, I used this link mentioned in the comments:

- *[Archived: Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages, Python-ldap](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap)*
- placed that [wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuptools#Package_format) (.whl file) into my reviewboard install directory

Then, executed the following commands

```
easy_install pip
pip install python_ldap-2.4.20-cp27-none_win32.whl
```

(because I had Python 2.7 and a 32-bit install at that)

```
easy_install python-ldap
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070063/installing-python-ldap-in-a-virualenv-on-windows

Answer (score 14):

For those having the same issue of missing *Iber.h* on [Alpine Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux), in a [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) image that you are trying to adapt to Alpine for instance.

The package you are looking for is: openldap-dev

So run

```
apk add openldap-dev
```

Available from version 3.3 up to [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge).

Available for both armhf and x86_64 Architectures.

Comment: Good for alpine-based images. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

On [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_Linux) 22, you need to do this instead:

```
sudo dnf install python-devel
sudo dnf install openldap-devel
```

Comment: Still true for F25

Answer (score 6):

I had problems with the installation on Windows, so one of the solutions is to install the `ldap` package manually.

A few steps:

- Go to the page [pyldap](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyldap) or/and [python-ldap](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap) and download the latest version `*whl`.
- Open a console then cd to where you've downloaded your file like `some-package.whl` and use:

  ```
  pip install some-package.whl
  ```

The current version for `pyldap` is 2.4.45. On a concrete example the installation would be:

```
pip install .\pyldap-2.4.45-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

# Or
pip install .\python_ldap‑3.3.1‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl
```

Output:

```
Installing collected packages: pyldap
Successfully installed pyldap-2.4.45
```

You can install the proper version for Python-3.X though using following command:

```
# If pip3 is the default pip alias for python-3
pip3 install python3-ldap

# Otherwise
pip install python3-ldap
```

Also here is the link of PiPy package for further information: [python3-ldap 0.9.8.4](https://pypi.org/project/python3-ldap/0.9.8.4/)

#### OR

ldap3 is a strictly RFC 4510 conforming LDAP V3 pure Python client library. The same codebase runs in Python 2, Python 3, PyPy and PyPy3: https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3

```
pip install ldap3
```

```py
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SAFE_SYNC

server = Server('my_server')
conn = Connection(server, 'my_user', 'my_password', client_strategy=SAFE_SYNC, auto_bind=True)

status, result, response, _ = conn.search('o=test', '(objectclass=*)')
# usually you don't need the original request (4th element of the returned tuple)
```

Answer (score 4):

On [openSUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE) you need to install the packages `openldap2-devel`, `cyrus-sasl-devel`, `python-devel` and `libopenssl-devel`.

`zypper install openldap2-devel  cyrus-sasl-devel python-devel libopenssl-devel`

Answer (score 4):

Python 3 does not support *python-ldap*. Rather install *ldap3*.

Answer (score 4):

For [Alpine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux) [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29):

```
apk add openldap-dev
```

If the Python version is 3 and above, try

```
pip install python3-ldap
```

Answer (score 4):

To correct the error due to dependencies to install the python-ldap: [Windows 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7) and [Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10)

Download the [whl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuptools#Package_format) file:

[http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap).

Python 3.6 suit with

```
python_ldap-3.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Deploy the file in:

> C:\python36\Scripts\

Install it with:

```
python -m pip install python_ldap-3.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 3):

For *most systems*, the build requirements are now mentioned in [python-ldap's documentation](https://python-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html#build-prerequisites), in the "Installing" section.

If anything is missing for your system (or your system is missing entirely), please let maintainer know!
(As of 2018, I am the maintainer, so a comment here should be enough. Or you can send a pull request or mail.)

Comment: Thanks, might be worth noting that if you're running python3, you would need  python3-devel, rather than python-devel.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python2.7-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev slapd ldap-utils python-tox lcov valgrind
```

- Debian Reference: *[Build prerequisites, Debian](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/installing.html#debian)*
- For others: *[Installing python-ldap](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/installing.html)*

Comment: Why install valgrind?

Comment: @BlakBat Best to ask the maintainers that, it's their recommendation. [Source](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/installing.html#debian)

Answer (score 3):

As of December 2021 there was/is a strange problem with the ldap library (at least in [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux)/[Manjaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjaro)).

While installing `python-ldap` (at 'Building wheel for python-ldap'), I got the message 'ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-ldap':

```
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lldap_r
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

A workaround is provided at *[Support for OpenLDAP 2.5+ #432](https://github.com/python-ldap/python-ldap/issues/432#issuecomment-974799221)*.

I cite:

> As a workaround create the file /usr/lib64/libldap_r.so with content
> INPUT ( libldap.so ). The approach works on all systems that use a GNU
> ld-compatible linker.
>
> ```
> # cat > /usr/lib64/libldap_r.so << EOF
> INPUT ( libldap.so )
> EOF
> ```

Comment: Manjaro user confirms :D

Answer (score 2):

On OS X, you need the Xcode CLI tools.  Just open a terminal and run:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 2):

For [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux)/[Manjaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjaro), for me, it helped with the following command:

```
yay libldap24
```

Comment: It worked on Manjaro, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As a general solution to install Python packages with binary dependencies [1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-ldap
# Installs system dependencies (but not the package itself)
pew workon my_virtualenv # Enter your virtualenv
pip install python-ldap
```

You'll have to check the [name of your Python package on Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) versus [PyPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Package_Index). In this case they're the same.

Obviously, it doesn't work if the Python package is not in the Ubuntu repositories.

[1] I learnt this trick when trying to `pip install matplotlib` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

In [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) 11:

```
pkg install openldap-client # For lber.h
pkg install cyrus-sasl # If you need sasl.h
pip install python-ldap
```

Answer (score 1):

Also adding `libzbar-dev` during the installation of `python-ldap` when building **Docker** solved it for me.

The full command becomes:

```
apt-get install -y python-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libssl-dev libzbar-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Ubuntu

The package `python-dev` is deprecated or not longer available. You can use this instead:

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev python2-dev python2 python-dev-is-python3 libldap2-dev libssl-dev
pip install python-ldap
```

---Edit---
[image: trying to install python-dev]

Comment: Re *"is deprecated"*: On what version of Ubuntu? And what version of Ubuntu was it tested on? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76695713/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Why `python2-dev` and `python2`? Why are they necessary?

Comment: From [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768446/i-cant-install-python-ldap/49760133#49760133): *"Python 3 does not support python-ldap. Rather install ldap3."*

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) (it covers answers as well). And also [Edit: or Update: (bad practice on Stack Overflow)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles/131011#131011) (near ***"Changelogs"***)

Comment: To repeat a previous comment: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** `"Edit:", "Update:", or similar` - the answer should appear as if it was written today!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! What isn't clear?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Windows machines, you can find the 'python-ldap' wheel in [this link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap) and then you can install it.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using [Alpine Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux),

```
apk add openldap-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip3 install python-ldap
```

Comment: Can you please explain what this does?

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A hack answer for FreeBSD 13.1 (yes, I know this is deep South of best practices, but I just needed a quick fix):

```
pkg install openldap24-client

cd /usr/local/include/python3.9
ln -s ../<all of the below> .

lber.h
lber_types.h
ldap.h
ldap_cdefs.h
ldap_features.h
ldap_schema.h
ldap_utf8.h
openldap.h
sasl

pip install python-ldap
```

Comment: How is it supposed to work? Why does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install libldap2-dev (`sudo apt-get install libldap2-dev`), but python-dev is also important. Remember to use the version you have (`sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev` or `sudo apt-get install pythonX.X-dev`)