# Installing python-ldap in a virtualenv on Windows

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I'm working on a Django project that is using an ldap authentication module. This is working on our server but I am running into issues getting this running on my windows dev machine.

My environment is using virtualevn and when trying to install pip python-ldap I receive the following message:

```
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, many Python modules have trouble installing on Windows. The error you're receiving is one that I was never able to get fixed, even given the vast amount of information available on the web. Give this link a try for a pre-compiled version: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap

Comment: I installed python_ldap‑3.4.0‑cp311‑cp311‑win_amd64.whl on win10 x64 like a charm!

Answer (score 34):

To expand on @Brandon's answer, to install using the pre-built wheel:

1. Ensure you have pip 19.2+ installed:

   ```
   $ pip --version
   pip 19.2.3
   ```

   Upgrade it just in case:

   ```
   $ python -m pip install -upgrade pip
   ```
2. Check your Python version and architecture (32/64 bit) https://stackoverflow.com/a/10966396/1026:

   ```
   $ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version)'
   3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
   ```

   or look at "compatible tags" reported by pip:

   ```
   python -m pip debug --verbose
   ```
3. Download the matching pre-built `*.whl` from https://github.com/cgohlke/python-ldap-build/releases

   For example given the above Python I picked "python_ldap‑3.2.0‑**cp37**‑cp37m‑win_**amd64**.whl"
4. Install it with:

   ```
    pip install path\to\your.whl
   ```

Comment: I couldn't get the latest build 38 to work but I did get build 37 (which he noted) to install successfully! 
`python_ldap‑3.2.0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`