# Failed building wheel for python-ldap (windows) *first stackoverflow ask*

Tags: python-2.7, ldap, openldap, flask-login, python-ldap

I've installed flask, flask_login, and ldap in the virtualenv for my flask package (to authenticate ldap users with the usernames & passwords of the other users at my company).

When I run my flask app, I get "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'initialize'"

I'm tried "pip install python-ldap"
but I get a red error (sandwiched between other white text) that reads:
"Failed building wheel for python-ldap"

I have thoroughly examined these:
[How to install python-ldap on a python 2.7 virtualenv on windows without compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918188/how-to-install-python-ldap-on-a-python-2-7-virtualenv-on-windows-without-compili)

[Installing python-ldap in a virtualenv on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070063/installing-python-ldap-in-a-virtualenv-on-windows)

https://www.python-ldap.org/docs.html

https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6988?page=0,1

to no avail.
I've had this error for days now...

(also:

> > > pip install openldap

gives:

Collecting openldap
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openldap (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for openldap

...(in and outside of my venv) if that information helps)

I had this error last week and after switching work computers, I recreated the virtualenv and installed all of the other packages and dependencies successfully.

my requirements.txt file contains these lines after a line of git stuff:

click==6.7

Flask==0.12.2

Flask-Login==0.4.0

itsdangerous==0.24

Jinja2==2.9.6

ldap==1.0.2

ldap3==2.2.4

MarkupSafe==1.0

pyasn1==0.2.3

Werkzeug==0.12.2

Has anyone successfully installed python-ldap into a flask virtualenv with windows? If so... how?!

Answer (score 5):

Go to:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap

download **python_ldap-2.4.38-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl** in the same directory that your **venv folder** is listed under

(ex.)

```
/myrepo
    /myapp
      /myapp
      /venv
      /run.py
      /python_ldap-2.4.38-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

install the .whl file while inside of your venv

```
venv\Scripts\activate

pip install python_ldap-2.4.38-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

The error

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-ldap

can occur for several reasons. You actually have to look at what happened above this line. In my case, I just had to install missing dependencies to build `python-ldap`. You can look them up [here](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.3.0/installing.html#build-prerequisites). For CentOS 8, I had to install:

```
sudo dnf install openldap-devel python3-devel gcc
```

to make

```
python3 -m pip install --user python-ldap -U
```

work.