# Import ldap in python gives gives "DLL load failed" error

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

I'm using the "import ldap"  in a python code. This is on a windows 10 machine.
I installed the python-ldap module

```
pip3 install python-ldap
```

Installed the dependencies based on the instructions at [Python Can't install packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261546/python-cant-install-packages/64262038#64262038)
Also resolved all the pip deployment issues based on [Installing python-ldap in a virtualenv on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070063/installing-python-ldap-in-a-virtualenv-on-windows/58235938#58235938)
I'm now getting the following error when executing the import ldap statement. am I missing something here? Any ideas to resolve it?

```
thon39\site-packages\ldap\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    import _ldap
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ldap: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit the unofficial Python binaries page:

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap)

Download the appropriate WHL package for your system.
For example, if you're using Python 3.8 on an x64 system, download `python_ldap‑3.3.1‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl`

(hint: do NOT download the `+sasl` version unless you have the Cyrus SASL code running on your system...)

Start the VirtualEnv for your project, if you're using one (`C:\Users\youruser\.virtualenv\YourVirtualEnv\Scripts\activate.bat`) -- if you're not, skip this step.

Then run `pip3 install C:\Path\To\python_ldap_x.x.x-cpXX-cpXX-winXX.whl` and this should install the Python DLL (pyd) file for you.