# How do I install python-ldap in a virtualenv on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ldap, virtualenv

I keep getting GCC compilation errors:

```
$ pip install python-ldap
...
compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: can't install python-ldap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768446/python-cant-install-python-ldap)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found this blog post which has the answer:

http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2012/10/installing-python-ldap-in-virtualenv-on.html

Essentially, you need to ensure you have the necessary development libraries installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev python-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev
```

Comment: Good find. If you plan to compile from source more often, the 'build-essential' meta package is good to have aboard as well.

Comment: I didn't know about this! Link for the lazy: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/build-essential

Comment: Appreciated, your answer helped me too. :)

Comment: This does not work on Ubuntu 16.x.  I do not know why.  But it gives the same complaint even after the apt-get line above.