# virtualenv python-ldap install error

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv, python-ldap

Please don't call this a duplicate.

All the answers have so far only 'solved' the problem by installing the ldap and other development packages globally, which doesn't solve the problem of not being able to install the python-ldap package in the virtual environment.

Examples include: 
[How do I install python-ldap in a virtualenv on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134826/how-do-i-install-python-ldap-in-a-virtualenv-on-ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev python-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev
```

I am using ubuntu 14.04, python 2.7 and flask in my virtual environment.

When I run `pip install python-ldap`, I receive the following error.

```
    copying Lib/ldap/schema/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/schema
copying Lib/ldap/schema/models.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/schema
copying Lib/ldap/schema/subentry.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/schema
copying Lib/ldap/schema/tokenizer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/schema
copying Lib/ldap/syncrepl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap
file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
running egg_info
writing requirements to Lib/python_ldap.egg-info/requires.txt
writing Lib/python_ldap.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to Lib/python_ldap.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to Lib/python_ldap.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
reading manifest file 'Lib/python_ldap.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'Makefile'
warning: no files found matching 'Modules/LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'Lib/python_ldap.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
building '_ldap' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.21 -IModules -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sasl -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c Modules/LDAPObject.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/LDAPObject.o
Modules/LDAPObject.c:18:18: fatal error: sasl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sasl.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/home/kmertig/hd_request/hd_request/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-V4vhsl/python-ldap/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-NIR67Y-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/kmertig/hd_request/hd_request/include/site/python2.7/python-ldap" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-V4vhsl/python-ldap
```

If I try to pip install any of the suggested dev libraries so that they are inside my virtual environment, I get the following error.

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libsasl2-dev (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for libsasl2-dev
```

I can install all this stuff globally just fine, but that just plain defeats the purpose of using virtualenv.

I would really like to find a meaningful, virtualenv solution, since all I have been able to find is non-virtualenv solutions for a virtualenv question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Python package *python-ldap* requires some other libs (*libsasl2-dev*, …) which are not python libs (so you can't use *pip* to install them). So, to use them, you have to install them. Two solutions:

- use your package manager to install them (ex.: *apt-get*) ;
- download their source code and compile them locally (in your virtualenv) (useful for some libs in special cases).

Maybe you can try the second solution?