# Pyldap (to use Django Auth LDAP) install in a python3 virtualenv

Tags: python, django, active-directory, ldap, virtualenv

I am trying to install [pyldap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyldap) to use it with [django-auth-ldap](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/) but when doing:

```
 pip install pyldap
```

I get:

```
 In file included from Modules/LDAPObject.c:4:0:
 Modules/common.h:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

#### Important

I am using Virtualenv, witch was created in python3:

```
virtualenv -p python3 myvirtualenv
```

And I have already installed the development packages (I am in CentOS, found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13159938/4470542)) :

```
sudo yum install python-devel
sudo yum install openldap-devel
```

#### What I already tried

Create two new virtualenv:

- One with python 3.4 (using the command above) and the `pip install pyldap`doesn't work (with the error described above)
- One with python 2.7 (using the command above without `-p python3`)and the `pip install pyldap` works
- Install the package as root `sudo pip3 install pyldap`and it works but when I run in the django app in the virtualenv I get:

  ```
  import ldap
  ImportError: No module named 'ldap'
  ```

I pretend to use pyldap precisely because it supports python3 so I can't understand why this happens and how may I resolve it. 
If you can't answer this question directly but you know other library I may use for Active Directory authentication in Django please comment this question.

Comment: I don't know if this is a general question for virtualenv or if it is related to something more specific so please guide me so I may edit the question and make it more understandable.

Comment: What does `pip freeze | grep ldap` show?

Comment: Doesn't show anything

Comment: that means pyldap has not been install OR you have not done `source myvirtualenv/bin/activate`

Comment: I have virtualenv activated and pip freeze shows other packages I have installed. When I installed pyldap with sudo and I got a success message (installing again it says the only option is upgrade, witch I've tried and does nothing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot install a package into a `virtualenv` using `sudo`. You must use sudo only to install the dependencies. For example

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libssl-dev
```

**updated**: However if your system's default version of python is 2.x and your virtualenv is 3.x you will actually need to install python3-dev instead of python-dev.

For the actual installation

```
source myvirtualenv/bin/activate
pip3 install pyldap
```

You are using pip3 here so make sure that your virtualenv has been setup to use python 3 with a command such as the following:

```
virtualenv -p python3 myvirtualenv
```

You can find out if what version is actually being used by entering the python shell.

As a foot note, if you really want to install a package as root:

```
sudo -i
source myvirtualenv/bin/activate
pip3 install pyldap
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had already done that but my question wasn't clear enough (I already edited it, please check it again). I don't really want to install as root, I just want to install it and I am not able to

Comment: Are you still getting the missing python.h error? if not how about leaving out all that information including the installation of devel-packages. Also how about trying the install with the --verbose option of pip?

Comment: Same error, nothing changed. I added pip install --verbose to the question.

Comment: Updated answer. I think what you have is python.h for 2.xx you need to install python3-dev as well.

Comment: Successfully installed pyldap-2.4.25.1!! Thank you. The resolution was exactly that but CentOS 7 doesn't have the devel package so I needed to install the EPEL repository.

Comment: Please simplify the answer in relation to my question so it is easier for others to understand. The resolution was just installing the python3-dev

Answer (score 0):

You have to install python-dev package (assuming you use a Ubuntu/Debian Linux)

`sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Then try to install pyldap using pip3 without sudo.