# I can't find BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm running this code

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface')

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

print(soup)
```

and I'm getting this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'bs4'
```

I've installed beautiful soup using

```
sudo pip install beautifulsoup4
```

and there were no errors.

I thought it might have installed bs4 to my python 2.7 library, but I can't find it there. I also can't find my python 3 library anywhere. Any ideas what I should do to get python 3 to recognize beautifulsoup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium getting install under python 2.7 site packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108370/selenium-getting-install-under-python-2-7-site-packages)

Comment: "I also can't find my python 3 library anywhere" Sounds like you have some things to sort out. Also, show us whether this code was run in Python 2 or 3.

Comment: In order to avoid this kind of issues in the future, use `virtualenv`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that pip points to your python 2.7 installation, check pip version with `pip --version`

To make sure its installing to python 3, use pip3:

```
sudo pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```