# Are python-ldap's build dependencies needed to run?

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

Based on answers to the question [Python: can't install python-ldap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768446/python-cant-install-python-ldap), I see that the requirements for installing the `python-ldap` package with `pip` are:

- libsasl2-dev
- python-dev
- libldap2-dev
- libssl-dev

I'm building a custom Docker image that needs the `python-ldap` package, and I'm wondering if I can remove these build-necessities after installing / building things to keep my image small.

In short, **are these prerequisites required for python-ldap to run, or are they merely build requirements?**

If it's the latter, I'd like to clean up to minimize my footprint. I simply don't know enough about how the Linux development packages are used to know if they contain files used at run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*-dev` dependencies is generally only needed for compilation. After compiling `python-lap`, these dependencies should not be needed anymore.

Try removing theses dependencies and test the container.