# Error Installing python-ldap package

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, python-ldap

I'm trying to install the python-ldap package with PyCharm and it is not working out, i get the following error:

[image]

Error Message:

Collecting python-ldap
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/1c/28d721dff2fcd2fef9d55b40df63a00be26ec8a11e8c6fc612ae642f9cfd/python-ldap-3.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting pyasn1>=0.3.7 (from python-ldap)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a0/70/2c27740f08e477499ce19eefe05dbcae6f19fdc49e9e82ce4768be0643b9/pyasn1-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1_modules>=0.1.5 (from python-ldap)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/51/bcd96bf6231d4b2cc5e023c511bee86637ba375c44a6f9d1b4b7ad1ce4b9/pyasn1_modules-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, python-ldap
  Running setup.py install for python-ldap: started
    Running setup.py install for python-ldap: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Joan\PycharmProjects\prueba\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Joan\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\python-ldap\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Joan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-y2ot_u84\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Joan\PycharmProjects\prueba\venv\include\site\python3.6\python-ldap:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    copying Lib\ldapurl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    copying Lib\ldif.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\async.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\asyncsearch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\cidict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\dn.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\filter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\functions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\ldapobject.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\logger.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\modlist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\pkginfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\resiter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\sasl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\syncrepl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\deref.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\libldap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\openldap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\pagedresults.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\ppolicy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\psearch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\pwdpolicy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\readentry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\sessiontrack.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\simple.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\sss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\vlv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\extop
    copying Lib\ldap\extop\dds.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\extop
    copying Lib\ldap\extop__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\extop
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\schema\models.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\schema\subentry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\schema\tokenizer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\schema__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\schema
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\slapdtest
    copying Lib\slapdtest_slapdtest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\slapdtest
    copying Lib\slapdtest__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\slapdtest
    running egg_info
    writing Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'Doc.build'
    writing manifest file 'Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\slapdtest\certs
    copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\README -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\slapdtest\certs
    copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\ca.conf -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\slapdtest\certs
    copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\ca.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\slapdtest\certs
    copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.conf -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\slapdtest\certs
    copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.key -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\slapdtest\certs
    copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\slapdtest\certs
    copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\gencerts.sh -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\slapdtest\certs
    copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\gennssdb.sh -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\slapdtest\certs
    copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.conf -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\slapdtest\certs
    copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.key -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\slapdtest\certs
    copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\slapdtest\certs
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

```
running build_ext
building '_ldap' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Modules
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=3.1.0 "-DLDAPMODULE_AUTHOR=python-ldap project" "-DLDAPMODULE_LICENSE=Python style" -IModules -IC:\Users\Joan\PycharmProjects\prueba\venv\include -IC:\Users\Joan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include -IC:\Users\Joan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /TcModules/LDAPObject.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Modules/LDAPObject.obj
LDAPObject.c
c:\users\joan\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\python-ldap\modules\constants.h(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lber.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
```

Command "C:\Users\Joan\PycharmProjects\prueba\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Joan\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\python-ldap\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Joan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-y2ot_u84\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Joan\PycharmProjects\prueba\venv\include\site\python3.6\python-ldap" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Joan\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\python-ldap\

I'll appreciate all the help,

thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post the text content of the error instead of images.

Comment: It's hard to tell since the first image you've posted truncates the error message, but it looks like you're missing the openldap header files (and libraries).  Binary dependencies like that aren't managed by `pip install`.

Comment: oh ok guys, i just updated it

Comment: Duplicate?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768446/i-cant-install-python-ldap

Answer (score 6):

To correct the error due to dependencies to install the python-ldap

download the wheel file

```
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap
```

python 3.6 is suitable with

```
python_ldap-3.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Deploy the file in `c:\python36\Scripts\`

install it with

```
python -m pip install python_ldap-3.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 3):

For Windows what it worked for me in this case after tried many options was:

```
    python -m pip install --only-binary :all: ldap
```

Comment: wrong library (should be python-ldap, which does not work)

Answer (score 2):

It's because pip tries to compile OpenLDAP library and python-ldap is just a wrapper around binary lib. If you don't want to compile OpenLDAP library by yourself then I recommend this site: 
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Download wheel-file you need, according to python version you use, for example **python_ldap-3.2.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl** is for **Python 3.6 64bit**.

Then install:

```
python -m pip install python_ldap-3.2.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Python LDAP documentation](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.3.0/installing.html) you can see that it requires a series of packages in order to get a proper installation (pre-build requisites). The commands you need to run, depends on the OS.

Sadly, this is intended for Linux based OS's.

I hope it helps! Cheers