# Installing python-ldap fails with lber.h file not found in ubuntu 17.10 even after installing devel packages

Tags: pip, python-3.6, python-ldap, ubuntu-17.10

I am trying to install python-ldap package using pip. I am getting the below error while executing `pip install python-ldap`. I tried installing the package corresponding to ubuntu 17.10 ( Artful ) as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768446/i-cant-install-python-ldap) but no luck yet. What package am I missing ?

Solution in the above stack overflow question is to install 
`sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev python-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev`
But in 17.10 I could not see `libsasl2-dev` & `libldap2-dev` instead I could see packages `libsasl-2-2`& `libldap-2.4-2`. I installed those along with `phthon-dev` & `libssl-dev`. But still I am getting the below error.
Seems I am missing some package installation which has lber.h file in it.

Error I am getting :

```
 In file included from Modules/LDAPObject.c:8:0:
    Modules/constants.h:7:10: fatal error: lber.h: No such file or directory
     #include "lber.h"
              ^~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Python version - 3.6.3

Pip version - 19.1.1

Comment: [This Dockerfile](https://github.com/bbonnin/docker-hadoop-3/blob/master/Dockerfile) created FROM ubuntu:17.10 does the following: `sudo apt-get update
 && sudo apt-get install -y --reinstall build-essential && sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev python-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev`. Can you try this? Also I'm not  sure about `python-dev`; perhaps it should be  `python3-dev` or `python3.6-dev`.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -y --reinstall build-essential` Gives me below message.


Reinstallation of build-essential is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.

Next command
`sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev` Gives below message. Seems there is no such package in repos list.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libsasl2-dev

Same thing for libldap2-dev. libssl-dev is already installed.

Answer (score 27):

I have figured out the root cause myself. Issue seems to be the dev packages itself.
Need to install `libsasl2-dev`, `libldap2-dev` & `libssl-dev`. I was not able to see these packages in 17.10 as the main repository mirror urls are changed as the version is archived as per the below question.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141501/i-cant-run-sudo-apt-get-update-in-ubuntu-17-10

I have changed to 18.04 and after installing the above packages everything works great.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python3-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev ldap-utils tox lcov valgrind
```

Comment: This still works for Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 3):

On **Ubuntu 22.04**:

```bash
sudo apt install libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac M2 VMware Kali for windapsearch

```bash
sudo apt install libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev 

pip install -r requirements.txt
```