# Using python package in Google Build

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

In my `requirements.txt` I am attempting to download `python-ldap==3.2.0`. However, I need [these dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768446/i-cant-install-python-ldap). How should I download these using Google Build? I tried the following but got the errors:

```
Step #0 - "Dependency install": E: Unable to locate package libsasl2-dev
Step #0 - "Dependency install": E: Unable to locate package python-dev
Step #0 - "Dependency install": E: Unable to locate package libldap2-dev
Step #0 - "Dependency install": E: Unable to locate package libssl-dev
Step #0 - "Dependency install": Building dependency tree...
Step #0 - "Dependency install": Reading state information...
Finished Step #0 - "Dependency install"
2019/06/14 12:51:21 Step Step #0 - "Dependency install" finished
2019/06/14 12:51:21 status changed to "ERROR"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "ubuntu" failed: exit status 100
2019/06/14 12:51:21 Error updating docker credentials: failed to update docker credentials: signal: killed
2019/06/14 12:51:21 Failed to delete homevol: exit status 1
2019/06/14 12:51:24 Build finished with ERROR status
```

`cloudbuild.yaml`

```
steps:
# Install Dependencies
- name: 'ubuntu'
  id: Dependency install
  args: ['apt-get', 'install',
         'libsasl2-dev', 'python-dev', 'libldap2-dev', 'libssl-dev']
# Install Python Dependencies
- name: 'python'
  id: Pip install
  args: ['pip3', 'install', '-r', 'requirements.txt', '--user']
```

Then I tried

```
- name: 'ubuntu'
  id: Dependency install
  args: ['apt-get', 'update', '&&', 'apt-get', 'install',
         'libsasl2-dev', 'python-dev', 'libldap2-dev', 'libssl-dev']
```

But that also failed.

Comment: Where are you trying to deploy this too? Google Cloud Build is intended as a CI/CD/Builder tool to create artifacts (binaries or images) and deploy them somewhere else.

Comment: The reason why this doesn't work is quite clear. But how to solve it depends on what are your goals.

Comment: @LuizFerraz I'm trying to deploy a GCF that uses `python-ldap`. That library requires `'libsasl2-dev', 'python-dev', 'libldap2-dev', and 'libssl-dev'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Functions receives only your source code and a `requirements.txt` file to indicate which python dependencies it uses.
The GCF manager internally and automatically install those dependencies on the python environment that will run you function, you install system libraries to the GCF environment, but you may use the ones that are available ([here is the list](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/python-system-packages)). The library `libldap2` that you require is not available. So you can open an issue on their issue tracker to ask for it.

Now, although it won't help you, the error on GC Build is happening because only the workspace (the starting working directory and everything inside it) is shared between steps. Each step starts a docker container with the image specified in the `name` parameter and with the workspace mounted.
A more obvious demonstration that system changes are not shared is that using Ubuntu in one step, CentOS in another and Alpine in yet another. System libraries for each of them are very different, so they are clearly not shared.