# Airflow LDAP with anonymous user

Tags: airflow

Is it possible to setup Airflow authentication process with LDAP for admins and superusers allowing read only access for anonymous user?

I wish I could provide code sample or something, but I don't even know where to start. For now I have a working LDAP connection and an ability to login without filters with my user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so, you need to enable [RBAC](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.6/security.html?highlight=ldap#rbac-ui-security) along with LDAP.

> Airflow ships with a set of roles by default: Admin, User, Op, Viewer,
>   and Public. Only Admin users could configure/alter the permissions for
>   other roles. But it is not recommended that Admin users alter these
>   default roles in any way by removing or adding permissions to these
>   roles.

This [blog post](https://itsecureadmin.com/2019/02/apache-airflow-1-10-2-active-directory-authentication-via-ldaps/) shows how steps are done.

In the AIRFLOW_HOME directory:

1. modify airflow.cfg:

   - comment the existing LDAP configuration
   - comment 'authentication = True'
   - update 'rbac = True'

> It's worth noting that there are some [deprecated items](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#deprecate-legacy-ui-in-favor-of-fab-rbac-ui) in [webserver] section per latest version.

2. create `webserver_config.py` file in the AIRFLOW_HOME directory with below configurations.
3. truncate ab_user & ab_user_role table in your meta database
4. restart airflow-webserver
5. update AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Viewer" in `webserver_config.py`
6. restart airflow-webserver again, now any new user login will be treated as viewer, login as admin to change their role accordingly.
7. Ensure the python-ldap was installed: `pip install python-ldap`. In case getting error, following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768446/i-cant-install-python-ldap).

`webserver_config.py`:

```py
import os
from airflow import configuration as conf
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_LDAP
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = conf.get('core', 'SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN')

CSRF_ENABLED = True

AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_LDAP

AUTH_ROLE_ADMIN = 'Admin'
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True

AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Admin"
# AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Viewer"

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER = 'ldaps://$ldap:636/
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = "DC=domain,DC=organization,DC=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER = 'CN=bind-user,OU=serviceAccounts,DC=domain,DC=organization,DC=com'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = '**************'
AUTH_LDAP_UID_FIELD = 'sAMAccountName'
AUTH_LDAP_USE_TLS = False
AUTH_LDAP_ALLOW_SELF_SIGNED = False
AUTH_LDAP_TLS_CACERTFILE = '/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/$root_CA.crt'
```

Comment: thank you for a such detailed instruction, I'll check it today

Comment: Is it possible to configure AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE from LDAP groups, I don't want to hardcode registration role in webserver_config.py. Please let me know if there is any way to map it to ldap.