# Where to get liber.h file/package for Lua?

Tags: lua, luarocks

I'm trying to install the lualdap via luarocks with `sudo luarocks install lualdap`, but I am greeted with

```
Installing https://luarocks.org/lualdap-1.2.4.rc1-0.src.rock

Error: Could not find header file for LBER
  No file lber.h in /usr/local/include
You may have to install LBER in your system and/or pass LBER_DIR or LBER_INCDIR to the luarocks command.
Example: luarocks install lualdap LBER_DIR=/usr/local
```

#### Notes:

- I am on Lua 5.3.
- I've installed OpenSSL and HTTP.
- I've tried the `LBER_DIR=/usr/local` parameter.

---

I've looked around for what rock file I need to download to get this lber.h file, but am not having any luck with it. How can I get this lber.h file?

Comment: See this answer to a similar question for python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768446/i-cant-install-python-ldap#4768467

Comment: Huh, I thought that was specifically for Python... libsasl2-dev was unable to be found, but libldap2-dev worked! Thank you! If you put that in an answer, I can mark it for anyone else with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lber.h` is not a file specific to Lua, but part of a library that needs to be installed on your system in order for the `lualdap` rock to be compiled.

On Ubuntu-like systems, you can install it with:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libldap2-dev
```