# Apache Superset | CentOs | Docker | Single container

Tags: apache-superset, python-ldap

I am running into build/compile error for development files (header issue) python ldap integration with Apache Superset. Both of the modules are installed openldap-devel and python-devel.

https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.2.0/installing.html#centos

```
  In file included from C/libldap.c:5:
  C/libldap.h:10:10: fatal error: ldap.h: No such file or directory
   #include <ldap.h>
            ^~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for py3-libldap

ibldap.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/C/libldap.o
    In file included from C/libldap.c:5:
    C/libldap.h:10:10: fatal error: ldap.h: No such file or directory
     #include <ldap.h>
              ^~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't install python-ldap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768446/i-cant-install-python-ldap)

Answer (score 0):

That kind of error usually refers to some package you are missing. The question *[I can't install python-ldap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768446/i-cant-install-python-ldap)* discusses which packages are prerequisites to openLDAP and how to install them.

Comment: Awesome, I just tried it and looks like working, will keep you posted. I was setting this up in requirements.txt and was failing from there, but installed it directly and it worked!

Thank you!