# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenSSL' while creating Dockerfile

Tags: docker, flask, pyopenssl

I create the docker file for my flask app that is running on port 3000.
That is my docker file

<-----------------**Dockerfile**---------------------->

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 3000
COPY    ./requirements.txt ./
RUN     pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY    ./ ./
CMD     ["python","run.py"]
```

<--------------------- **requirements.txt**--------------------------------->

I generated it by using "pipreqs"

```
pyOpenSSL==20.0.1
Flask_Login==0.5.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.12
Flask_WTF==0.15.1
WTForms==2.3.3
Flask_SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
Flask_Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask==2.0.1
Pillow==8.3.2
secrets==1.0.2
```

<------------------------------**Error that I encounter**------------------------------>

```
E

RROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-aesbht7l/secrets_faf11378a9b945deb5114ab973cefa73/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-aesbht7l/secrets_faf11378a9b945deb5114ab973cefa73/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ub_x6ltz
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-aesbht7l/secrets_faf11378a9b945deb5114ab973cefa73/
    Complete output (12 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-install-aesbht7l/secrets_faf11378a9b945deb5114ab973cefa73/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        import OpenSSL
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenSSL'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-aesbht7l/secrets_faf11378a9b945deb5114ab973cefa73/setup.py", line 12, in <module>
        raise ImportError('Installing this module requires OpenSSL python bindings')
    ImportError: Installing this module requires OpenSSL python bindings
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/c4/166925e31bc06bfe49deb4dc3922584790a33b897509bac388acdc074a60/secrets-1.0.2.tar.gz#sha256=37075ab08607092e76da2b86e94dd38a0216ec80088a0a3f9220077750aeddf9 (from https://pypi.org/simple/secrets/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement secrets==1.0.2 (from versions: 1.0.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for secrets==1.0.2
```

**I even added pyOpenSSL in requirements.txt but the error keeps saying like that. Did I choose the wrong python image? Is it related to that?**

Answer (score 0):

Consider installing additional packages:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 3000

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libsasl2-dev python-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev

COPY    ./requirements.txt ./
RUN     pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY    ./ ./
CMD     ["python","run.py"]
```

(got the answer from here: [I can't install python-ldap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768446/i-cant-install-python-ldap))